# Populating a std::vector map using the operator[]?

Tags: visual-c++, stdvector

Am I overcomplicating this? Since I recently learned that with `std::vector` you can use the `[]` operator and it will add the entry if missing.

I have something a little more detailed:

```
using WeekendFutureItemHistMap = std::map<CString, std::vector<COleDateTime>>;
using WeekendFutureHistMap = std::map<WeekendHistAssign, WeekendFutureItemHistMap>;
```

`WeekendHistAssign` is just an `enum class`.

In my function I am populating it this way:

```
if (m_mapScheduleFutureHist[eHistAssign].find(strName) != m_mapScheduleFutureHist[eHistAssign].end())
    m_mapScheduleFutureHist[eHistAssign][strName].push_back(datAssign);
else
{
    m_mapScheduleFutureHist[eHistAssign].emplace(strName, std::vector<COleDateTime>{datAssign});
}
```

According to the [`std::vector operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) it states:

> Returns a reference to the element at specified location pos. No bounds checking is performed.

As a result it seemed the right thing to do is test for the existing first as done.

Did I overcomplicate it?

Answer (score 1):

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.resize(100);

v[0]=1;
v[1]=10;
...
```